# In an abelian category with no nontrivial Serre subcategories, does every short exact sequence split?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, abelian-categories

**Question:** Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category. Suppose that the only Serre subcategories of $\mathcal A$ are the zero category and $\mathcal A$ itself. Does it follow that every short exact sequence splits in $\mathcal A$?

**Notes:**

- The hypothesis of no Serre subcategories means that the locally coherent Grothendieck category $Ind(\mathcal A)$ has trivial Ziegler spectrum.
- The conclusion that short exact sequences in $\mathcal A$ split is [not quite as strong](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327899/name-for-abelian-category-in-which-every-short-exact-sequence-splits) as saying that $A$ is semisimple.
- If $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is a non-split short exact sequence, then there is at least a weak Serre class given by $\{X \mid Ext^\ast(C,X) = 0\}$ which is not all of $\mathcal A$ (though maybe it could still be zero). But I'm not sure how to get an actual Serre class out of this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The category of finite abelian $p$-groups (where $p$ is your favourite prime) is an abelian category with no proper nonzero Serre subcategories, but not every short exact sequence splits.

Comment: Or more generally, take the category of finite length modules for a non-semisimple local ring.